# React hook set state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Does setting a state with its current value triggering react to re-render?

Should I compares the new value with the current value before setting it?

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(123);

/*.....*/

const newValue = whatever();

/* do not trigger render if the value still the same */
if (newValue !== value) setValue(newValue); // like this
// or
setValue(newValue); // or just simply like this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is smart and will check the value for comparison before enqueuing a re-render.

> If your update function returns the exact same value as the current state, the subsequent rerender will be skipped completely.

See [this section](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) of their docs for more info

---

An important caveat is that because it uses the [`Object.is()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#description) for equality checking, it acts as you'd expect for simple variables like strings or numbers, skipping if the values are equal, but for objects (things in `{}`), it doesn't check the value but instead just whether the reference to the object is the same.
This means two identical objects will be seen as non-equal, and cause a rerender, whereas if you change the contents of an object but the overall object is the same, it will be seen as equal and not rerender.

Answer (score 0):

***By using:***

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(123)
```

and later in your code:

```
setValue(123)
```

It won't rerender.

***But if you use instead:***

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({myCoolNumber: 123});
```

and later in your code:

```
setValue({myCoolNumber: 123})
```

In this case it will do rerender because you are passing an object to the function setValue and that object is a different reference than the object you first passed to useState.